# setValue is not a property of EelementRef

Tags: javascript, html, angular, setvalue

I am testing this HTML form:

```
<form  name="editForm" role="form" novalidate (ngSubmit)="save()" #editForm="ngForm">
<input #inputValid type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre" id="field_nombre"
       [(ngModel)]="paciente.nombre" required/>
```

I test the validity of the input, which means if it is empty it should fail.
I referenced the `input` element using ViewChild in my component like this:
>

```
export class PacienteDialogComponent implements OnInit {

 @ViewChild('inputValid') inputValid: ElementRef;
 ......
```

And I test it like this:

```
fit ('If blank it should be invalid', async(() => {                  
   comp.inputValid.setValue('');
  //comp.inputValid.controls['paciente.nombre'].setValue(''); 
  //OUTPUTS CANNOT READ paciente.nombre of undefined
  expect(inputElement.valid).toBeFalsy();
}));
```

Th error that I get here is:

> SetValue is not a function.

And if I use controls the error is like in the comment of the line:

> cannot read property of undefined.

How can I test the validity of this input? Th eform is template driven of angular.

Comment: Why don't you just check `paciente.nombre`? There's no need for the viewChild

Comment: How? Th eonly way to take the reference of an HTMLElement is to use ViewChld

Answer (score 1):

First, I don't understand why you need to check this manually if you have a "required" in the input control.

Anyway, you should not check via the ViewChild component, you can check it directly to the field of your class that is binded to the form (aka paciente.nombre).

But, if you have a reason to access the html element, you have to use

```
comp.inputValid.nativeElement.value = .....
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: How can be an example of testing direcly paciente.nombre?? If its value is empty or not

Comment: Or betetr testing if it is a text or not

Comment: If you have <input type="text"....it will be a text! ;-)    To test if it is not empty just check "if (paciente.nombre !== '')

Comment: What do you mean??? The user may enter numbrs too!!! And this is wrong. I should test if it is only letters or numbers